# How to generate a superposition of m-level n-particle states $|j_{0} ,j_{1}, ....,j_{n-1}\rangle$ with $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} j_k \mathrm{mod}\ m \ = \ 0$?

Tags: quantum-state, circuit-construction

The m level n-particle state $|X_{N}\rangle$  is defined as

> $$\boxed{|X_{N}\rangle = \frac{1} {m^\frac{n-1}{2}}\sum_{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} j_k \mathrm{mod}\ m \ = \ 0}|j_{0}\rangle |j_{1}\rangle ....|j_{n-1}\rangle}$$

How can this state be prepared?

Answer (score 5):

To get you started, the $m = 2$ (qubit) case:

Start with n qubits all in the 0 state. Apply Hadamard gates to the first n-1 qubits. Apply n-1 controlled nots, each one controlled by a different one of the hadamarded qubits, and each targeting the nth qubit (the one we didn’t hadamard).

Here's an example circuit for $n=3$:
[image]

To understand how this works, recall how a controlled-not functions:

[image]

So, if after applying the Hadamard gates we have the state
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n-1}}}\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^{n-1}}|x\rangle|0\rangle,
$$
then after all the controlled-nots I'm suggesting, the final bit is in the state
$$
x_1\oplus x_2\oplus x_3\oplus\ldots \oplus x_{n-1}.
$$
The overall parity of the final $n$-bit string is
$$
x_1\oplus x_2\oplus x_3\oplus\ldots \oplus x_{n-1}\oplus (x_1\oplus x_2\oplus x_3\oplus\ldots \oplus x_{n-1})=0,
$$
as required.

As ChainedSymmetry pointed out, the $m$-dimensional generalisation is near-identical. You apply a gate
$$
|0\rangle\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}|i\rangle
$$
on the first $n-1$ spins. The controlled from each of these spins, targeting the $n^{th}$ spin, you apply a generalisation of the controlled-not of the form
$$
|j\rangle|k\rangle\mapsto|j\rangle|-j+k\text{ mod }m\rangle.
$$

Comment: For m = 3, we have $$
x_1\oplus x_2\oplus x_3\oplus\ldots \oplus x_{n-1}\oplus ((x_1\oplus x_2\oplus x_3\oplus\ldots \oplus x_{n-1}) \oplus (x_1\oplus x_2\oplus x_3\oplus\ldots \oplus x_{n-1}))=0,
$$ Am I correct?

Comment: @ChaitanyaReddy No, you have exactly what I wrote: $x_1\oplus x_2\oplus(x_1\oplus x_2)=0$

Comment: Sir, I think you considered n = 3 in the above comment. Please consider n (as variable) and m = 3 (m > 2) .

Comment: @ChaitanyaReddy ah yes, so I did, but mainly because you used the standard notation for addition modulo 2. What you wrote does not work for m=3 either. Just think about the case that I wrote down, but for addition mod 3.

Comment: Sir can I consider this as an example of quantum circuit which follows inherent parallelism?!

Comment: @ChaitanyaReddy I wouldn't, but that might depend on how you define it. If I were actively computing something, and went through this state as an intermediate state, then yes.

Comment: Sir, recently you modified j in generic c-not gate to -j. Why?

Comment: That’s what you need to get the outcome you desire.

Answer (score 3):

For the general case, $m>2$, do what DaftWullie said, except apply gates corresponding to the $m$-point [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) instead of the Hadamard gate (which is the 2-point DFT matrix).

**Edit Per Request**

For the $m=3$, $n=3$ use a gate ($M$) corresponding to the 3-point DFT matrix instead of the Hadamard gate to effect the transformation $\vert j \rangle =\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \sum \limits_{n=0}^2 e^{\frac{i 2 \pi jk}{k}} \vert k \rangle$.  Define $\omega \equiv e^{\frac{i 2\pi}{3}} = -\tfrac{1}{2} + i\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, and $M$ is explicitly 
$$M = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & \omega & \omega^2 \\ 1 & \omega^2 & \omega \end{bmatrix}$$
(note that $\omega^4=\omega$). The relevant circuit is almost identical to DaftWullie's except $H$ is replaced with $M$ and the computational basis now has three states.  Any other changes are superficial to aid the explanation.

[image]

You can see that $M \vert 0 \rangle = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(\vert 0 \rangle + \vert 1 \rangle + \vert 2 \rangle)$, so trivially
$$\vert \psi_0 \rangle= \tfrac{1}{3}(\vert 0 \rangle + \vert 1 \rangle + \vert 2 \rangle)\otimes (\vert 0 \rangle + \vert 1 \rangle + \vert 2 \rangle) \otimes \vert 0 \rangle.$$

Application of $\text{CNOT}$ between the bottom two registers gives
$$\text{CNOT} (\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(\vert 0 \rangle + \vert 1 \rangle + \vert 2 \rangle) \otimes \vert 0 \rangle)=\tfrac{1}{3}(\vert 0 \rangle + \vert 1 \rangle + \vert 2 \rangle) \otimes (\vert 0 \oplus 0 \rangle + \vert 0 \oplus 1 \rangle + \vert 0 \oplus 2 \rangle),$$
where $\oplus$ is addition modulo 3.  This gives
$$\vert\psi_1 \rangle = \tfrac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}(\vert 0 \rangle + \vert 1 \rangle + \vert 2 \rangle)\otimes (\vert 00 \rangle + \vert 01 \rangle + \vert 02 \rangle + \vert 10 \rangle + \vert 11 \rangle + \vert 12 \rangle + \vert 20 \rangle + \vert 21 \rangle + \vert 22 \rangle).$$

The same $\text{CNOT}$ process is repeated between the first and third register to get to $\vert \psi_2 \rangle$ and arrive at the desired result
$$\vert \psi_2 \rangle = \tfrac{1}{3 \sqrt{3}} \sum \limits_{p,q,r=0}^2 \vert p \, q \,  r \rangle.$$

Comment: Could you please give me some reference (link/textbook/example) for this concept.

Comment: @ChaitanyaReddy The DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform) is a generalization of the Walsh-Hadamard transform. You may check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_(general)) Wikipedia page. For a more pedagogical approach to the DFT (and subsequently QFT), you may refer to [Ryan O'Donnell's lecture(s)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXs6LNdQRjg).

Comment: @ChainedSymmetry could you please edit the answer for the case of n = 3 and m = 3. I understood DaftWullie's explanation for n  = 3 and m = 2 but I am unable to proceed for n = 3 and m =3.

Comment: @ChaitanyaReddy Sure, I just edited my answer to explicitly walk through the case of $n=3$, $m=3$.

Comment: @ChainedSymmetry In the transformation - M|0>, M is a 3x3 matrix and What should be the size of |0>? Is it 3x1? 
If it is 3x1 then how to generate it?

Comment: @ChaitanyaReddy In this case $$\vert 0 \rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}, \;\;\; \vert 1 \rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\0 \end{bmatrix}, \;\;\; \vert 2 \rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\1 \end{bmatrix}.$$  The computational basis is generally just the columns of the $m$-dimensional identity matrix.

Comment: @ChainedSymmetry The way the problem is solved is beautiful. Where can I find reference to this and similar kind of problems?